# cmake generated file path using configure_file

Tags: cmake

I am practicing using the cmake tool, and some parts of the CMakeLists.txt is belows:

```
configure_file(print_info.cpp.in print_info.cpp @ONLY)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/print_info.cpp)
```

so I have a question, where does the generated "print_info.cpp" located?

and in target_sources why should I write ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/print_info.cpp?

In my understanding, the print_info.cpp file should be located in the same directory with main.cpp file.

Comment: [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) treats non-absolute output paths relative to the current binary directory: "A relative path is treated with respect to the value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`." And that treatment is taken into the account by your code. As for the `main.cpp`, it is most likely located in the **source** directory in your project.

Comment: There are 2 corresponding trees: the source tree starting at the directory containing the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` dir (`-S` command line option) and the build tree using the build directory provided as command line option as root dir (`-B` command line option). Child relationships are introduced using `add_subdirectory`. This could result in both source and build tree overlapping, but actually that's discouraged, since it prevents you from setting up multiple configurations based on the same sources.

Comment: Relative source file paths and similar are usually searched in the source tree, paths to generated files usually placed in the build tree though and this is why you need to specify the absolute path in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/print_info.cpp`.